# How to migrate(change) from Ubuntu desktop to Ubuntu Server?

Tags: 14.04, migration

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version, I would like to use Ubuntu 14.04 Server.

Is it possible to migrate (change) from Ubuntu desktop to Ubuntu server without losing data from my system?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open your terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Then type  `sudo tasksel` in terminal

[image]

It will open in terminal with options & there you can choose Ubuntu Server with space-bar and then continue. It will download and install Ubuntu Server tools.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do I enter into Ubuntu server

Comment: This installs the packages for Ubuntu server but does not *remove* the packages for a desktop installation. That may or may not be what is needed.

Comment: @AJ Your current Ubuntu already having server tools. right now your Ubuntu is like Ubuntu Server + Ubuntu Desktop. Eliah Thank you.

Comment: One word of caution: **never ** use tasksel to remove something, it will remove all packages needed for that task, even if you installed them manually.

Comment: @guntbert nice point.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo tasksel install server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-server linux-image-server
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
```

These commands can help you to competly convert an Ubuntu Desktop to Ubuntu Server. It work on Ubuntu 14.04 ;D

Comment: When `sudo apt-get install linux-server linux-image-server` it says not found. When rebooting, it says image is corrupted. You'll get a brick at the end.