# Can I upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop to Ubuntu 21 (04/10) Server without losing data?

Tags: server, upgrade, gui

Edit:  To clarify I mean to upgrade to either 21.04 or 21.10.

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498362/how-to-migratechange-from-ubuntu-desktop-to-ubuntu-server) that is relevant, but the comments on the answers indicate that Ubuntu Desktop either is not uninstalled or that there is a serious risk of unintentionally removing needed packages or of outright bricking the machine.  Obviously neither of these is ideal.  I wondered if the problems might be resolved if the change were made as part of an upgrade rather than a standalone uninstallation of the desktop capabilities.  I have already added most of the server components, and I no longer need the GUI capabilities which are taking up sorely needed space on the hard drive.

Comment: Ubuntu releases using the *year.month* format (*deb* based systems) are different products to those using the *year* format (*snap* only products), and the *year* products  only come out on *even* years (eg. Ubuntu Core 20). You cannot upgrade a 20.04 (server/desktop) system to a Core 20 product (server) without re-install (there is no Ubuntu Core 21)

Comment: I did not even know there was a _year_ format; I just meant either 21.04 or 21.10.  But thanks for the info.

Comment: Canonical/Ubuntu introduced *snap* only products in 2016 & thus use the *year* to highlight they are different products, eg. Ubuntu Core 16 was the 2016 release of the server product for devices/appliances or cloud use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tested and supported path from 20.04 to 21.04 nor to 21.10. There are a lot of hacks of varying quality.

Recommended: The simplest, safest, and fastest path is to back up your data and services, then install 21.10 Server over the older Desktop system.

- The backup is in case you select the wrong option during install; if you select the correct option, then all your data and services will still be there.